# Can I install the same OS more than once in multiboot mode?

Tags: multiboot

I'm using OpenELEC on my Pi.

Recently I installed an addon that broke one of my existing addons.

I got an idea that instead of going crazy trying to fix that, I might **install the same distro 2 times on the same SD card** and let each addon live in its own distro.

I know this might seem like overkill, but I thought it might do the job.

I'm just not sure if there's an easy way (as in Noobs / Berryboot / etc.).
Googling around I only saw "multiboot distro X and Y" - never "X and X".

Any suggestions welcome.

**Note:** I know this can be done "the hard way" - i.e. manually partitioning the SD card and installing the distro on both. I wanted to know if there's some tool that can do that easier - i.e. partition SD - click to transfer image to 1st partition - click to transfer image to 2nd partition - done.

Comment: Have you considered simply purchasing a second sd card?

Comment: @MohammadAli Use a sufficiently large enough sd card (32 or 64 GB?) and use separate partitions.

Comment: I do have more than one SD card, but I don't want to have to switch in this case (same distro). I know it can be done technically. I just don't want to fiddle with it too much (making partitions is OK, but messing around with bootloaders and doing everything by hand seems like too much hassle when you can put a distro image to your SD with one click).